# Всем привет. Реализую приложение на React в котором также есть яндекс карты. Есть компонент SearchControl, как мне получить значение с этого инпута?

Tags: reactjs, яндекс-карты

Мне просто нужно считывать значения с SearchControl и записывать его в переменную. На ванильном JS ответ вроде как нашел, а на React не могу найти. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

```
<YMaps>
        <Map
          defaultState={{
            center: [57.15, 60.05],
            zoom: 9,
            controls: [],
          }}
        >
          `<SearchControl/>`
          <FullscreenControl />
          <Placemark geometry={[57.2399, 60.09]} />
        </Map>
      </YMaps>
``
```